# SQL Query to COUNT fields that match a certain value across all rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying (and failing) to craft a simple SQL query (for SQL Server 2012) that counts the number of occurrences of a value for a given date range.

This is a collection of results from a survey.

So the end result would show there are only 3 lots of values matching '2' and 
6 values matching '1'.

Even better if the final result could return 3 values:

```
MatchZero = 62
MatchOne = 6
MatchTwo = 3
```

Something Like (I know this is horribly out):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(0) AS MatchZero, 
  COUNT(1) AS MatchOne, 
  COUNT(2) As MatchTwo 
WHERE dated BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01'
```

I don't need it grouped by date or anything, simply a total value for each.

Any insights would be greatly received.

```
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------+-----------+------------+
| QuestionId | friendly | professional | comfortable | rate | recommend |   dated    |
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------+-----------+------------+
|          3 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2014-02-12 |
|          9 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2014-02-12 |
|         14 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    2 |         0 | 2014-02-13 |
|         15 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2014-01-06 |
|         19 |        0 |            1 |           2 |    0 |         0 | 2014-01-01 |
|         20 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2013-12-01 |
|         21 |        0 |            1 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2014-01-01 |
|         22 |        0 |            1 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2014-01-01 |
|         23 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2014-01-24 |
|         27 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2014-01-31 |
|         30 |        0 |            1 |           2 |    0 |         0 | 2014-01-27 |
|         31 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    0 |         0 | 2014-01-11 |
|         36 |        0 |            0 |           0 |    1 |         1 | 2014-01-22 |
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------+-----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM((CASE WHEN friendly = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN professional = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN comfortable = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN rate = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN recommend = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
          ) AS MatchZero,
       SUM((CASE WHEN friendly = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN professional = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN comfortable = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN rate = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN recommend = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
          ) AS MatchOne,
       SUM((CASE WHEN friendly = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN professional = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN comfortable = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN rate = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
           (CASE WHEN recommend = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
          ) AS MatchTwo           
FROM . . .
WHERE dated BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-02-01';
```

Comment: Many thanks. Accepted at the answer as this was exactly the chunk of code I needed for my purposes. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to count the zeros, ones and twos for a particular (or each) column in your table. If this is correct, then you could do something like this:

```
select sum(case when your_column = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as zeros
     , sum(case when your_column = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ones
     --- and so on
from your_table
-- where conditions go here
```

If you want to count the total for more than one column, enclose the needed `case...end`s in the `sum()`:

```
sum(
    (case when column1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
    (case when column2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
    -- and so on
) as zeros
```

Comment: Many thanks @Barranka. This was certainly the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Going with a simple unpivot you can get the desired result with less coding.
By simply changing the date range the correct count of each question type is counted.

```
SELECT 
    RANKING, COUNT(*) AS CNT 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        friendly,professional,comfortable,rate,recommend 
    FROM 
        your_table 
    WHERE 
        dated >= '1/1/1900' AND dated <= '1/1/2015'
) AS U UNPIVOT 
(RANKING FOR QUESTION IN (friendly,professional,comfortable,rate,recommend)) AS UNP
GROUP BY
    RANKING
```